# MySQL left join variation - selecting even on missing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I could already figure out how to join and select rows from a primary table, even if secondary table does not have matching rows. What I want is a little different.

```
Table A:  id, pid
Table B:  id, pid, uid, aid
```

What I want is all `pids` in table A, with matching `aid`, if it exists,  for a given `uid`

That is, if example data is:

Table A:

```
1,  p1
2,  p2
3,  p3
```

Table B:

```
1, p1,  u1,   abcd
2, p1,  u2,   pqrs
3, p2,  u1,   wxyz
```

I want to select:

```
p1,   abcd
p2,   wxyz
p3,   NULL
```

(all entries for `u1`,  use aid=NULL if there is no entry).

So basically, I have tried:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.pid=B.pid WHERE uid='u1'
```

and it does not work (I understand why it wont).

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is different from a left join?  Why in your example is the first record always `1`?

Comment: in your query replace `where` with `and`

Comment: When you put the restriction condition in the where clause it essencially makes it an inner join.  Move it to your join.  oh.. as @FuzzyTree has suggested. :)

Comment: @FuzzyTree / paqogomez -- yes, what you said works and I learnt something new.  If either/both of you could add this as an answer, I could upvote/accept :).  Thank you!

Comment: @WorkWise Gordon has already posted it as an answer. If you like you can accept his answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `left join`, but you need to move the condition on the `b.uid` to the `on` clause from the `where` clause:

```
select a.id, a.pid, b.aid
from a left join
     b
     on a.pid = b.pid and b.uid = 1;
```

Comment: why we move b.uid from WHERE to ON, what difference does this make ?

Comment: WHen the condition is in the `where` clause, it turns the `left join` into an `inner join`, so it filters rows from the first table.  In the `on` clause, this doesn't happen.

Comment: so isn't WHERE with condition better as we already get filtered results ?

Comment: @Rockse . . . No, unless you really intend an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should solve your issue

```
SELECT A.pid, aid
FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.pid = B.pid and B.uid = "u1";
```

**OUTPUT**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eaa05/10

Your query

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.pid=B.pid 
WHERE uid='u1'
```

**OUTPUT**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eaa05/12

The issue is with `WHERE`, `LEFT JOIN` works as an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes this is exactly what I was doing and as above comments explain, this doesnt work in my case.

Comment: @WorkWise: Please post a sqlfiddle if possible